# Time complexity for a sorted container

Tags: python, time, complexity-theory

I'm using Python's SortedDict container for a problem and was wondering what the time complexity of the getting the highest key would be:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
treeMap = SortedDict()
treeMap[1] = [4]
treeMap[1].append(6)
treeMap[3] = [9]
print(treeMap.keys()[-1]) # get the highest key in the sorted dictionary, should be 3
```

I know that most operations in SortedDict are O(log(n)) but I'm specifically confused about treeMap.keys()[-1]. For a normal dictionary, d.keys() is O(1) in python3..is d.keys()[-1] O(1) as well? Is it log(n) in case of sorteddict or O(n) as I need to access the last element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sortedcontainers` `SortedDict` maintains the key order, under the covers, in a `sortedcontainers.SortedList`. So the operation you're asking about is really `SortedList.__getitem__()`. From [the docs](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html):

> __getitem__(index)[source]
> Lookup value at index in sorted list.
>
> sl.__getitem__(index) <==> sl[index]
>
> Supports slicing.
>
> Runtime complexity: O(log(n)) – approximate.

So it's log time.

Comment: What does the "approximate" mean, though?

Comment: "Approximate" means "the whole story is far too involved to summarize briefly, and in practice doesn't really matter". See the docs: http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance-scale.html?highlight=complexity